# Drop duplicates with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

| index | so_id |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 390 |
| 10 | 395 |
| 10 | 405 |
| 11 | 390 |
| 11 | 395 |
| 11 | 405 |
| 12 | 390 |
| 12 | 395 |
| 12 | 405 |

The desired output would be the following:

| index | so_id |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 390 |
| 11 | 395 |
| 12 | 405 |

Basically my goal is to drop duplicates on the column 'index' while keeping a different ascending value for the column 'so_id'

Comment: in your real data, you always have the same values in so_id for each index ?

Comment: no I dont, the values change and also I don't always have 3 so_id for each index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it but importantly, pay attention to comment above.

```
df=df.sort_values (by=['so_id'])#Sort df
```

Create temporary column `t` which is a classification of `so_id` and `resort` `df` back to original    `df=df.assign(t=df['so_id'].ne(df['so_id'].shift(1)).cumsum()).sort_values(by='index')`

Create a temporary classification of index

```
df=df.assign(t1=df['index'].ne(df['index'].shift(1)).cumsum())
```

Select where two classess above are similar

```
df=df[df['t']==df['t1']].drop(columns=['t','t1'])

print(df)

    index  so_id
0     10    390
4     11    395
8     12    405
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I created a dictionary which maps old index to new index by adding values to a set to get unique values and then sorting in the ascending order which is required. After dictionary is formed, we can check if values in a particular row match with the data inside the dictionary, if it matches then that combination is correct and we don't do anything to that row, if it doesn't match we simply drop that row:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[10, 390], [10, 395], [10, 405], [11, 390], [11, 395], [11, 405], [12, 390], [12, 395], [12, 405]], columns=['id', 'so_id'])
idx_map = {}
idx=set()
new_idx=set()
for row in df.iterrows():
    idx.add(row[1]['id'])
    new_idx.add(row[1]['so_id'])

for i in range(len(idx)):
    idx_map[sorted(idx)[i]]=sorted(new_idx)[i]


for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if idx_map[row[0]]==row[1]:
        continue
    else:
        df = df.drop(idx)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   id  so_id
0  10    390
4  11    395
8  12    405
```

Here, idx_map dictionary looks like this:

```
{10: 390, 11: 395, 12: 405}
```